# Release Management in Azure Devops with Git

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I need an assistance not only in finding proper solution but even in formulation the question so I'm not sure I gave the topic right title. We are small development team that recently moved from SVN to Azure devops GIT. While working with svn we had a separate back-office system developed by one of us that gave good response to 'management of code releases'. We have to manage code releases for different clients on different servers. Everytime bug or task was closed our system knew to increase version counter by one so that in the end we could know what is range of ids of the tasks or bugs in every release for every server. How can I find something similar in  Azure devops GIT? I read about RM, RG, Pipelines, Retentions but nothing seems to be solution to our needs

Comment: probably you should use gitversion task along with some others to version the artifact itself.

Comment: check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/overview?view=azure-devops-2019&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops

Comment: Which technology do you use? If .net, look at https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your pipelines are built on Azure Pipelines, please take a look at:

- [Customize Run (build) number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)
- [Customize Release names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops#how-do-i-manage-the-names-for-new-releases)

Check [this](https://medium.com/faun/overwrite-build-number-for-your-azure-pipeline-71fd95043f12) blog out for a detailed example. If this doesn't work for you, give [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-versioncounter) marketplace extension a try.

Comment: Thanks! I found out interesting things thanks to your answer. My problem is still (as much as I understood working with pipeline) that pipeline are configured depending on code commits and releases but the requirement of our company is that version counter is incresed when bug or task is closed. So that clients can see which task or bug is coming into specific version. Can this be achieved with pipelines??

Comment: blog article pointed to by link has been removed by author.